# NodeJS - multiple objects split across multiple files but in the same namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a multiplayer board game server in NodeJS, and I have several different objects like Game, User, Board etc. Currently, all of these objects reside in a single 'sever.js' file which is executed by NodeJS.

As my project grows, this single file is becoming increasingly crowded and hard to navigate.

What I would like is to split these objects into multiple js files, but without having to use the require function all over the place.

I wish to continue creating objects like this -

```
game = new Game();
```

And not this -

```
game = new (require('game')).Game()
```

--

Edit:

What is the correct NodeJS way of doing things?

Answer (score 7):

Well, there are a few small things you can do.

First, when you define your class in another file (to be required) you define `module.exports` directly, i.e.

```
module.exports = function Game() {...};
```

And, then instead of:

```
game = new (require('game')).Game()
```

You can do:

```
game = new (require('game'));
```

Or, what I prefer, is to define all the requirements at the top:

```
var Game = require('game'),
    User = require('user');

// Use them:
new Game();
new User();
```

You could create some fancy loader that traverses the directly and automatically requires all JS files, but I really don't think it's worth it.

Comment: Is including them at the top like that considered best practice? What's the NodeJS recommended way of doing things?

Comment: +1. This (requiring at the top) is common practice in Node apps and libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You can use global. 
in Game.js:

```
global.Game = function(){};
```

in User.js:

```
global.User = function(){};
```

in main.js:

```
require('Game.js');
require('User.js');

var game = new Game();
var user = new User();
```

Comment: This is my favorite method. It's analogous to including C++ header files, but it will pollute your global scope if using modules with similar names.

Answer (score 1):

You can load them at the beginning:

```
var Game = require('game').Game;
// Do a bunch of stuff
var game = new Game();
```

However, I personally wouldn't. Can't say exactly why I don't like the idea, but I don't.

Comment: Are you content with using require all over the place just to do a simple task like instantiating an object? I want to do things the "right way", but I'm not sure what the right way is.

Comment: I see your point, but I have actually never had this problem because I just keep everything in one file. While I have written several things in Node, they have without exception been fairly small projects and simply bookmarking bits of code in the editor has been sufficient, but I can see that if you were dealing with a very large volume of code this could get tedious/impossible.

Comment: It really kind of is.