# Using AJAX to POST to Node server

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I literally just found out about Node.js today and I've done so much reading that its making my head hurt.  I have the node server up and running.  I also have a .JS file on the node server that writes to a text file. I would love to see just one variable (name) get passed from my Javascript application to the server running Node.js so that the Log file gets updated.  From what I have read AJAX is the best way to do this.  Can someone get me going in the right direction with a small code example on how to do this?

Code of File.js on Server Running Node

```
var fs = require('fs'), str = 'some text';
fs.open('H://log.txt', 'a', 666, function( e, id ) 
{
  fs.write( id, str + ',', null, 'utf8', function(){
  fs.close(id, function(){
  console.log('file is updated');
});
```

});
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do what you mentioned:

Make a quick http server, look at the request variable of any connection, and get the parameters that were passed in, and write that to the file.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var inputText = req.url.substring(1);
    processInput ( inputText );
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Completed.');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

**Edit here:** of course, you still need to define what `processInput` is.

```
function processInput ( text )
{
    // What you had before
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.open ('H://log.txt', 'a', 666, function (e, id )
    {
        fs.write ( id, text + ',', null, 'utf8', function() {
            fs.close(id, function() {
               console.log('file is updated');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This way, when you send a request to

127.0.0.1:1337/write

it would write the word "write" into the file (if processInput writes the input).

Another way to process would be with a parameter in the URI. More information on how to do this is found exactly [here at the nodejs api](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverrequest).

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Kaushik- thanks for the great post. Can you elaborate on 127.0.0.1:1337/write?  Won't I need to call the .js file on the server end somehow in order to pass the variable to it?  Sorry, I'm just now learning this.  Blow my comment up now ;)

Comment: Hey DaBears. When you make a request to your node server, you have all the information about the request within the `req` object.

The way node works is its really just a javascript runner. But what makes it powerful is that it has the `http`, `net`, and a lot of other packages which allow you to create highly scalable servers. It's very flexible, but you need to specify a lot of things. Look into [how http requests are made](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) and you'll understand how the parameter `write` gets passed in. Also check the latest edit.

Comment: Hi Kaushik-  This is starting to make more sense to me.  for http request, I added the javascript code from [link]http://www.websitetoolbox.com/tool/support/117 inside of my javascript application and changed the url to http://mynodeserver:8000 and I got a Success popup when I hit my javascript application in a client web browser.  Next I added your first code and the modified function you posted into a .js file and saved it on the node server.  I assume I needed to run that js file in cmd prompt on node server before it can be picked up by the httprequest in my javascript app?I get Sysntax er

Comment: Refer to [this SO question on how to split across multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561559/nodejs-multiple-objects-split-across-multiple-files-but-in-the-same-namespace).

Comment: Thanks Kaushik, I was able to get the log file part working using your method.  I'm going to attempt to make this httprequest from the portion of the code that creates the cookie in the javascript app now.